# Simple passing of Matrices ie. cv::Mat to functions in OpenCV2.4

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new to opencv and I have a doubt with one of the simplest operations in coding: Passing values to functions.

Heres what I want to do,

1. Initialize a `cv:Mat` in the main function with say, values from 0 to 50.
2. Pass this matrix as an argument to a function `foo()` which in turn simply prints out the values of each element in the matrix.  Thats it.

Now I have read in multiple places that when these matrices are passed, it is only the header that gets passed, not the actual data. Then how am I still able to read out the values of this matrix in the called function as if the entire matrix was passed?

Comment: Where are these places? Can you share references to them?

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To understand what's going on you need to take a look at **[C++ constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.1)**, more specifically **the [copy constructor](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/)**.

When you create a `cv::Mat` from another `cv::Mat`, as in:

```
cv::Mat a = cv::imread("huge.png", 1);
cv::Mat b = a;
```

the **copy constructor** (which is a function) of `cv::Mat` is called to perform the copy of the object. Before I talk about what happens in the copy procedure, you must realize that as `cv::Mat` is used to store images, larger images might occupy hundreds of megabytes in memory. So what the **copy constructor** of `cv::Mat` does in the example above is copy the entire header (height, width, depth info and others) of `a` into `b`, but instead of copying the entire data/pixels of `a` (which might be hundreds of MB), it just points (using a pointer) to the original data of `a`.

In other words, **not copying the entire image data is an optimization/performance decision**.

Now, consider this code that calls a function and passes `cv::Mat` as a parameter:

```
void do_something(cv::Mat src)
{
    // changing src pixels will be the same as changing orig pixels
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat orig = cv::imread("huge.png", 1);
    do_something(orig);
    return 0;
}
```

If you have studied how to pass parameters to functions, you know that calling  `do_something(a);` will **[pass the parameter by value](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=343473)**. This means that it will try to copy the content of `orig` into `src`, however, this procedure activates the copy constructor of `cv::Mat` which will not make a hard copy of the data as I've just explained.

Solution to this problem? If you are writing `do_something()` and you just want to make a real copy of `orig`, just create a new `cv::Mat` and call the method `copyTo()`:

```
void do_something(cv::Mat src)
{
    cv::Mat real_copy = src.copyTo();
    // operating on the data of real_copy will not affect orig
}
```

But remember, if `src` is ~100MB calling `copyTo()` to make the real copy will occupy another ~100MB of memory, which means that in a single function call your program just went from 100MB to 200MB. Keep this in mind when designing your system. Good luck.

Comment: Excellent. Its like you read my mind and answered the exact question I had. Thank you very much Sir. Much appreciated.

Comment: Cool, just click on the checkbox near it to select it as the official answer.